# phpfmt - Don't add _ before private and protected functions/variables

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I am working on an oldish project made by another developer, and as I am the new maintainer I'd like to reformat the php code according to the PSR-2 ruleset.

I am using `visual studio code` with the extension `phpfmt`. It works quite well but it transforms this

```
<?php
private $newPassword = '';
protected function describe(ModelSchema $s){
```

to this

```
<?php
private $__newPassword = '';
protected function _describe(ModelSchema $s)
{
```

Everything else is perfect, but I don't need those extra dashes, as they break my app.

So I'd like to tell `phpfmt` to avoid that rule.

By looking at the documentation i haven't seen nothing that seems related to this topic: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kokororin.vscode-phpfmt

How can I exclude that rule to be applied?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you can disable it by disabling CakePHP code style: https://github.com/kokororin/vscode-phpfmt/issues/72

```
"phpfmt.cakephp": false
```